# You must provide at least one recipient email address. PHP mailer

Tags: php, email

I'm currently experiencing a very strange issue trying to set up a simple mailer from a form. I've literally used the code on many sites seems to be working fine. But on this particular one I seem to be getting the Error "You must provide at least one recipient email address."

This is the code that i've been using

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$name = $_POST['name'];
    $user_email= $_POST['email'];
$query = $_POST['message'];

$message = file_get_contents('email.html');
$message = str_replace('{{name}}', $name, $message);
$message = str_replace('{{email}}', $user_email, $message);
$message = str_replace('{{message}}', $query, $message);


$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->From      = $user_email;
$email->FromName  = $name;
$email->Subject   = 'Talking Together Speech Therapy Enquiry From- '. $name;
$email->Body      = $message;
$email->AddAddress( 'barry.tickle12@gmail.com​' );

if($email->send()){
  // Trigger when email sends
}else{
//Trigger when email doesn't send
    echo  $email->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Can a specific server setup be causing this? Other sites on the same server seem to be working fine with it apart from this particular one.

*** Edit ***

Var dumped all POST Requests to the file and nothing is being returned empty.

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['email']` is not empty ? Could you `var_dump` it ?

Comment: means $user_email is empty or not a valid email address

Comment: I wish that was the case, unfortunately everything is coming through as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a check to see that you have all the required data ?

```
$email= $_POST['email'] ?? '';

if($email){
    /** Your code goes inside this if */
} else {
    /** Show error */
}
```

Comment: Just in the process of doing this now! Just a quick question, what's the ?? syntax in php?

**Edit all fields are being posted

Comment: It's a PHP 7 feature -> http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Makes it a little easier to check if isset has been set or not

Answer (score 0):

Try using new version of AddAddress():

```
$email->addAddress('recipient@domain.com', 'Name');
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately